# How to align text in center inside div from top and bottom using css

Tags: html, css

I got problem in css adjust while working with div tag text should come in center from top and bottom and if text is large and when minimize browser window iot should come responsive  but none of this expectation met
here is js fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/ou4n2gxy/3/

(1 Text should come in center from top ,bootom,right,left
(2 when minimize browser window it should get responsive means it should not cut some portion of text

```css
#wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 90%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 60%;
  height: 80px;
  margin: auto;
  vertical-align: middle;
  display: table-cell;
}

#content {
  display: block;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row ">
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-sm-2" id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2" id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>

  <div class="col-sm-2" id="wrapper">
    <div id="content">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The basic syntax for centrally aligning (both horizontally and vertically) is:

```
.textClass{   
    position: absolute;
    left:50%;
    top:50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}
```

Comment: This does not provide a complete answer. Note `position: absolute` requires a positioned parent element that serves as the base for the 'absolute' positioning (default is the viewport, which isn't always appropriate).

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS is a bit messy; you have two `width` properties with different values so the browser is not sure what to follow. You also have two `margin: auto`.

I hope this is exactly what you want to achieve:

```
#wrapper{
  display: block;
  width:90%;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  height: 80px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
#content{
    width:80%;       
}
```

I removed the `display: block` and `margin: auto` in `#content` because the default display of a `div` is `block` and since it is centered inside the box, there's no need for that `margin: auto`. When you resize the browser, it would wrap the text instead of showing an overflow.

Answer (score 0):

Your container div should have position: relative, and your inner div should have:

```
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
```

Check this pen:

https://codepen.io/giannidk/pen/bgxjLW